# How to make my Roblox clickable block stop moviing

Tags: lua, roblox

I made a block that has a script that makes it move when clicked

part = script.Parent

```
function move()
    part.Position = part.Position + Vector3.new(3,0,0)
    wait(1/30) -- Delay
    if part.Position.X > 45 then -
      part.Position = part.Position - Vector3.new(5,5,5)
      wait(1/30) -- 
    end
end

part.ClickDetector.MouseClick:connect(move)
```

This block will go through other objects no matter what, and I just need to find a way to make it unclickable after a certain distance.

Comment: probably a http://xyproblem.info

Answer (score 0):

> This block will go through other objects no matter what, and I just
> need to find a way to make it unclickable after a certain distance

Well your code moves the block for a certain distance each click.

Check your blocks position when clicked. If the new position is outside the clickable range, disconnect the event listener.

Also note that `connect` is deprecated. You should use `Connect`. Please read the Roblox manual.

https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/articles/events#disconnecting-a-function

> ```
> local points = Instance.new("NumberValue")
> points.Name = "Points"
> points.Value = 0
>  
> local connection
>  
> local function onPointsChanged(newPoints)
>   print("Points: " .. newPoints)
>   if newPoints >= 50 then
>       -- Stop listening for changes if we have at least 50 points
>       connection:Disconnect()
>   end
> end
>  
> connection = points.Changed:Connect(onPointsChanged)
>  
> -- Trigger some changes
> points.Value = 25
> points.Value = 100
> points.Value = 0  -- Prints nothing because we called Disconnect()
> ```

Answer (score -1):

> This block will go through other objects no matter what

Do you mean that it does not collide with objects? Like if there's a wall in its way it will go through anyway? If so maybe you should make it tween and stop if it detects collisions.